# Does this sentence make sense?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary, alternatives

I'm trying to write a subtitle for my report but my English vocabulary is letting me down. Could you please help?

I'm trying to let the below sentence mean something like, *"Here's my list of suggestions with a guide to increase the workflow in the department"*.

**Explanatory suggestive guide for an enhanced workflow within the department.**

Your suggestions and answers are appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: 'suggestive' doesn't mean what you think it does;) Most BrE speakers would immediately think of meaning 2 in [OALD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/suggestive?q=suggestive) The sentence would work without that entirely.

Comment: @Tetsujin It's the same in AmE.

Comment: I think this is more of a word choice question than a proofreading question because the asker has explained what they are trying to say, so I am voting to leave it open.

Comment: @ColleenV: I disagree, obviously (it's my *proofreading* closevote). If ***I*** were heading up such a report, I wouldn't bother with the *suggestions/[suggestive?]* bit anyway. Assuming OP isn't the *boss*, it should be pretty obvious they're only *ideas to be considered*, not a *statement of company policy*. But with any luck the suggestions will be good, and the boss *will* endorse them. So I'd take the optimistic route and go for a report name that wouldn't need changing if/when that happens: *Guidelines for enhanced departmental workflow*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The question is phrased as "my vocabulary is letting me down, this is what I'm trying to say, this is my attempt, is it OK or is there a way to make it better." That is a much better quality question than the "Do you see any errors in this paragraph that I wrote?" type question that we agree should be closed as proof-reading. How is this different from any other word or phrase request other than the title of the question could better reflect the content of the question?

Comment: @ColleenV: I've only just scrolled down to see Khan's suggestion, which is much the same as mine, and gives much the same reasons for discarding unnecessary verbiage. But none of that is really relevant to using/learning *English* - it would be the same in any language. The only truly "ELL-relevant" thing I see here is Tetsujin's first comment, but in fact OP doesn't appear to be asking *Is this a valid use of the word "suggestive"?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers so it's not off topic because it's proof reading. Why isn't asking for help on how to express something in English that you don't have the vocabulary to express on topic? If the asker had left off their attempt at a title, would it be on topic?

Comment: @ColleenV: I've cvt'd as Off Topic *because* it's proofreading. If you disagree, there's not much I can do about that. So far as I'm concerned, if OP's English is good enough for him to write *"Here's my list of suggestions with a guide to increase the workflow in the department"*, it's good enough for him to think up his own report title. All I see here is a request for ***suggested titles***, which looks to me like [Writing advice or critique requests](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think we have a disconnect in what we perceive as proof-reading and I want to understand your perspective. Is it proof-reading in your opinion because it asks "Does this title express this?" and there isn't a specific word or construction highlighted as a concern? How could the question be reworked to be on-topic? I appreciated the attempt to construct a suitable sentence because I'm a big fan of the "show your research/effort" advice, so I may have a blind spot.

Comment: @ColleenV: I don't see how this question could be "reworked" to meet *my* idea of On Topic for ELL. To repeat - all it does is ask for suggested titles for a report OP needs to produce for work. There are no "principles of the English language" involved, and it would be slightly ridiculous to claim there could be a "right answer". I only get one vote, and I've used it as I saw fit. I don't want to see questions like this here, because they contribute nothing to the goal of producing a knowledge base for future visitors wishing to learn English. You're free to think different, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could go with something like Ben has recommended. It wouldn't be wrong, but it might be a little vague, especially if someone were to read the title by itself.

(If I saw those words, I might wonder if someone was asking for suggestions from the workforce.)

An alternative perhaps worth considering is:

> Suggested Ways to Increase Department Workflow

Comment: I like this one better, too.

Answer (score 0):

> Suggestions for Increasing Workflow in the Department